All the differences between minkube and regular kubernetes
Given a kubernetes release version,

Does minikube run all the components that a regular kubernetes cluster would using the component executables (api-server, kube-proxy etc.) without modification (without slimming down)?
What are any other differences in regards to functionality, if exists?
Are the only differences, the difference of purpose, number of nodes and resources used?

In other words, is there no technical difference between a regular kubernetes cluster and minikube cluster other than the non functional differences?
